# Creating custom OAuth2 Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

There is a project I am working on using asp.netcore 3.1. d app is a web API and will b consumed by multiple clients(web browser, android and Windows forms). How can I build the OAuth2 server in c# to protect my API.

Answer (score 2):

Most companies don't build their own Authorization Server, since it is a job for security experts. Instead they use a cloud provider, and these are often very low cost or free.

In the early days this is a good learning guide and will save you a lot of time. You can then focus on OAuth integration into your UIs and APIs.

As long as you keep security in your UI and API **standards based** you will then be able to easily swap between providers later - or use an open source one perhaps.

Here are a couple of resources of mine that you might find useful. My early code is in NodeJS, but based on OAuth messages, so easily translatable to .Net Core:

- [Setting up an Authorization Server](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/15/developer-domain-setup/)
- [Initial Tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/)
- [OAuth Messages - see Step 16 for API Integration](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/)